# drop down list failed in excel of mac

Tags: macos, excel, drop-down-menu

I used `Data Validation` to create a drop-down list in Excel. After choosing `list` on the Data tab, I set the *source* value to `1,2,3`. It worked in Excel of Microsoft Windows, but it failed in Excel of Apple MacBook Air. In MacBook Air, the list have only one item "1,2,3". Is anything different to create a drop-down list in MacBook Air?

By the way, another question: how to make the arrow of drop-down list always visible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localized settings can have different elements for separating multiple arguments.

So on your Windows system this might be the comma and on your mac maybe the semicolon.

Please be aware that this can be changed by the user after default has been chosen by the program on installation/first use

Comment: semicolon doesn't work either. Where can I find the setting for separating multiple arguments?

Comment: use the fx just on top of your  spreadsheet, go to (dont actually use it just select it!) formula `sum`. See that in the preview in the bottom it shows SUM(number1,number2) but then with your local separator where i have a comma. Now thats the one you should use in your excel

Comment: I just did what you said. It showed the separator is semicolon. Then I tried it again and it did work. I didn't know why it failed last time. Maybe due to my carelessness. I am sorry about it. It is really strange to use different separator in Mac and Windows. Do you know how to make the arrow of drop down list always visible?

Comment: in the windows environment you will be able to tick a box in the *Data Validation* window with description "In-cell dropdown", Chances are that is also there in the Mac version and it might be unticked. Tick it again and there you are! See this video for example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVHEXde2Uog&feature=player_detailpage#t=117s

Comment: I am using Chinese Office software. There are two check box options: one is overlooking void value and the other one is providing arrow for drop down list. Both of them are ticked. But when you select the cell, the arrow comes up. When you unselect the cell, the arrow disappears. How to make the arrow always show up no matter if the cell is selected or not?

Comment: ah, well the behaviour you see is what it is supposed to do. If you want a permanent drop down box you should enable the developer tab in the ribbon (Office button > Excel Options > Popular > Show Developer tab in the Ribbon) There you will find a button called Insert click it and then select the form control called ComboBox (2nd icon by default). Now drag in your sheet, and there it is. Right click and select Format Control to link it to a range of cells. Good luck